# "This page is slowing down Firefox": how to get the JS line/function triggering it?

Tags: javascript, firefox, freeze

Some websites tend to freeze FF (and sometime more), with one escape possible when triggering the "This page is slowing down Firefox" message allowing to stop it before.
→ Is there a way to find the JS line or function that caused it ? (e.g. when the message is displayed ). I don't find it in the console debugger.

Comment: Try using the performance tab of the developer tools?